# Oracle Apex 5 how to show the highlight rows' from your table with a condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Hy guys,
i have create a simple interactive report for show all record from my table.
i need highlight some rows in output with a condition.
how can do it?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried, what output do you need, etc. SO is not a free-code source. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried the option "Highlight" in the actions menu of the interactive report ? This is when you run the report in the app, not in the page builder. The path in 19.2 is Action > Format > Highlight. I suppose it is similar in your version. This feature has been around for many versions.

Comment: Koen Lostrie. You have reason, but when i logout from the application, the "Hightlight" disappears. How can leave it forever?

Comment: You need to save the report. Actions -> Report -> Save Report

Comment: Save report as "primary report" then it will be shown for all users by default

Comment: Check out the information in the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/ir_using.htm#HTMDB25950

Comment: Perfect thx all.